# How to compare a checkbox with my database value? | Angular

Tags: angular

How can I compare a dynamic created list of checkboxes with my database value?

If the value in my database is not null, its a checked box.

That´s the way how I generate my checkboxes. I already tried something with `ngModel`, but I have no idea how to handle this.

```html
<div class="list-container">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let char of allATypes">
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="char.checked"> {{char.bezeichnung}} </mat-checkbox>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

My goal is something like this pseudocode `if(aType.allgemeinesMerkmal.bezeichnung) { char.checked = true) }`
How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, just make sure that you're binding the `ngModel` to the correct property.

- Loop through the source array in the component template using `*ngFor`.
- For each item, add a `checkbox` and bind it to the property that holds the `checked` indicator, using `ngModel`.
- If you want to return the changed checkboxes (checked/unchecked) to the server again, you have to use two-way binding `[(ngModel)]="...."`, otherwise you can only use one-way binding `[ngModel]="..."`

**component.ts**

```js
// I used this static data, but you should use the data that comes from the server. 
allATypes = [
  {
    title: 'Test 1',
    enabled: true,
  },
  {
    title: 'Test 2',
    enabled: false,
  },
  {
    title: 'Test 3',
    enabled: true,
  },
];

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.allATypes);
  // here you can send the updated data to the server.
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of allATypes">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.enabled">{{ item.title }} </mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Here's a working [StackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xgzgbl) demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by API hit:

```html
<div class="list-container">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let char of allATypes">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="check_id_db(char.id)">
            {{char.bezeichnung}}
        </mat-checkbox>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

In your `.ts` file, as you have injected service:

```js
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }
```

Work to hit HTTP:

```js
check_id_db(id){
    this.apiService.check_val(id).subscribe(res=>{
        console.log.(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer but what i want is that the site loads with already checked checkboxes if the values are the same like in the database.

Comment: can you plz share you full code (html and ts) so I can answers better.

Comment: This is my problem, i dont know how to begin.

Comment: you can write  your logic in "check_id_db" function as we pass id of selected check box in "check_id_db" function .